# grepl on two vectors element by element

Tags: r, grepl

I'd like to apply `grepl` on two vectors to see if elements of the first vector are available in the corresponding elements of the second vector. For example

```
grepl(c("bc","23","a2"),c("abcd","1234","zzzz"))
```

And since `bc` is in `abcd`, `23` is in `1234` and `a2` is not in `zzzz`, I'd like to get `TRUE TRUE FALSE`. But, instead here is what I get:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
Warning message:
In grepl(c("bc", "23", "a2"), c("abcd", "1234", "zzzz")) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try using `mapply` here:

```
fun <- function(x, y) {
    grepl(x, y)
}

mapply(fun, c("bc","23","a2"), c("abcd","1234","zzzz"))

  bc    23    a2 
TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: no need to define a function beforehand `mapply(grepl, c("bc","23","a2"), c("abcd","1234","zzzz"))` works just as well

Answer (score 5):

The `stringr` package (which relies on `stringi`) offers naturally vectorized `regex` functions:

```
require(stringr)
str_detect(string=c("abcd","1234","zzzz"),pattern=c("bc","23","a2"))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Notice that the order of arguments is different with respect to `grep`.

Comment: Or you could just use the original package (and I don't think regex is needed here) `stringi::stri_detect_fixed(c("abcd","1234","zzzz"), c("bc","23","a2"))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use also `purrr`:

```
purrr::map2(c("bc","23","a2"),c("abcd","1234","zzzz"),
            function(x,y) grepl(x,y))
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE
```

If you want to stay with `base`:

```
   unlist(Map(function(x,y) grepl(x,y), my_list[[1]],my_list[[2]]))
   bc    23    a2 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the or operator

```
grepl(c("bc|23|a2"),c("abcd","1234","zzzz"))
```

Comment: This allows anything on the left to match in any element on the right. The OP asked specifically for a comparison of corresponding elements, so this answer is wrong.